# Exclude Careers favourites from advertisements

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs, advertising, bookmarks

The Careers advertisement box on Stack Overflow always shows jobs I've already favourited on Careers. 
As users already know their own favourites, it is useless to advertise them again.
The job-offering companies also want to show ads to a broader audience instead of reaching the same people again and again.
Better show some new jobs similar to existing favourites!

Comment: Makes total sense, but we have a lot of work to do before we can jump on something like this

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Comment: @Juice Please consider changing or removing the status tag.

Answer (score 3):

It's a fine line to walk, and making a smarter algorithm is *probably* a lot of work (I will use programming job advertisements as my example).

For example, if you advertise a C# position to someone who answers a lot of ***C#*** tagged question then you know you're matching their skill-set/interests. Although it's quite likely that this person already has a job in the field there exists *a chance* that they will click on that advertisement out of curiosity.

However, if you start advertising ***C#*** jobs to people commenting on ***PHP*** or ***Java*** tagged questions you're far less likely to generate any interest.

An algorithm that establishes which people have ***some interest*** in C# although it may not be their **main** occupation is a lot more work than just sticking to the basics, and may ultimately not result in that many more hits.

Comment: I've seen a similar answer to a different question. SE already has bad experience with such an algorithm. People answering MySQL questions might not want offers for DA. My request is a simple "exclude favourites" which does not require a complex algorithm and this is not covered by you answer.

Comment: @phobie - you're welcomed to write your own answer :-)